# Solving an equation defined within a subfield

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem, but have had absolutely zero progress in the last few hours.

Let F be the subfield consisting of real numbers of the form $p+q\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ where $p,q$ are of the form $a+b\sqrt2$, with $a,b$ rational. Represent
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}{2-3\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}$$
in the same form.

Incase I can save anyone some time, the above fraction can be simplified to
$$\frac{-58+30\sqrt2 -70\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}+45\sqrt2\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}{34}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}$. Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ and simplify.

\begin{align*}
  \frac{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}{2-3\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}
      &= \frac{(1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2})\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{(2-3\sqrt{2+\sqrt2})\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}} \\
      &= \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}-3\sqrt{2}} \\
      &= \frac{(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2})(2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}+3\sqrt{2})}
              {(2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}-3\sqrt{2})(2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}+3\sqrt{2})} \\
      &= \frac{2(2-\sqrt{2}) + 3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} + 6}
              {4(2-\sqrt{2}) - 18} \\
      &= \frac{10-2\sqrt{2} + 5\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{-4\sqrt{2}-10} \\
      &= \frac{(10-2\sqrt{2} + 5\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}})(4\sqrt{2}-10)}
              {(-4\sqrt{2}-10)(4\sqrt{2}-10)} \\
      &= \frac{60\sqrt{2}-116+40\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}-50\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{68} \\
      &= \left(-\frac{58}{34}+\frac{30}{34}\sqrt{2}\right)
            + \left(\frac{20}{34} - \frac{25}{34}\sqrt{2} \right)\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I imagined that it simplifies to the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ and I had to use the property of closure under multiplication to obtain a/b. I take it that this isnt the case then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you do what I suggested, you will get a fraction with terms including $\sqrt{2}$ as well as $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ in both numerator and denominator. Then rationalize the denominator and it will all work out.

Comment: I played around with that quite alot, the $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ term remains, or atleast changes to something that is equally unhelpful

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your calculations are correct, you're almost there:

$$\frac{-58+30\sqrt2 -70\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}+45\sqrt2\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}{34}$$

$$= \left[-\dfrac{29}{17} + \dfrac{15}{17}\sqrt{2}\right] + \left[-\dfrac{35}{17} + \dfrac{45}{34}\sqrt{2}\right]\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: I was expecting a solution to be in the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$, and I figured that what you wrote would somehow simplify to it.

Comment: The question states clearly that $p,q$ are of the form $a + b\sqrt{2}$ for rational $a,b$. I have put $p$ and $q$ in brackets for easier identification.

Comment: I was expecting a solution to be in the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, and I figured that what you wrote would somehow simplify to it. Maybe by using an arbitrary p,q and the multiplicative colsure of F to multiply p,q by the original denominator and obtain another element thats in the set, and somehow solve for the new p and q.

If this is really the answer, I have absolutely no idea why my professor put it on the problem set (second year in the best one of the most reputable math schools).

I'm going to take your answer in good faith, and play with it in a bit. Thank you vm.

Comment: That would be on a par as expecting $\dfrac{a + b\sqrt{2}}{c + d\sqrt{2}}$ to be rational. Although it *might* happen, it's not *typical*.

Comment: This solution expresses the number in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$, not $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$.